# How can I retrieve existing Object (on salesforce) with Java script?

Tags: apex-code

How can I retrieve existing 'Opportunity' object with Java script (on Sales application)?

custom button's javaScript 'onClick' section.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

//Get Opportunity object 
var op = "{<Retrieve Opportunity Object ?>}";

//Call insertJob method by passing that Opportunity object
sforce.apex.execute("JobService","insertJob",{o:op});
```

Apex Class.

```
global class JobService {
webService static void insertJob(Opportunity o) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses the merge syntax to get the opportunity Id:

```
var op = sforce.connection.query("Select Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = 
'{!Opportunity.Id}'").getArray("records")[0];
```